# I'm prevented from using a switch statement that doesn't cover all possible cases

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement, option-type

```
return degrees % 90 != 0? Optional.empty() : Optional.of( switch( degrees ) {
            case 0 -> NORTH;
            case 90 -> EAST;
            case 180 -> SOUTH;
            case 270 -> WEST;
            //default -> null;  is there something I can put here to make empty Optional?
        } );
```

Above returns an Optional containing an enum of the cardinal directions. The code has previously ensured that these are the only 4 possible values of `degrees`. But IntelliJ IDEA won't allow this, complaining that the `switch` hasn't handled all possible values.
I've searched for a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation to allow this; the closest I've found is `SwitchStatementWithoutDefaultBranch`, but it doesn't help.

It seems like there should be an annotation that would allow this.

I know the code can be rewritten to work around the issue, but why can't this be handled?

Comment: Eliminate the ternary and just use `Optional.ofNullable`?

Comment: Change `case 270` to `default`?

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. (I'm adding your solutions to the answer I'm about to write.) However, I still think there should be a @SuppressWarnings annotation to allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a ternary operator here. `Optional.ofNullable` will give you an `Optional.empty()` if you pass in `null`, so you can do:

```
return Optional.ofNullable( switch( degrees ) {
            case 0 -> NORTH;
            case 90 -> EAST;
            case 180 -> SOUTH;
            case 270 -> WEST;
            default -> null;
        } );
```

Comment: Great! However, I still think there should be a @SuppressWarnings option to allow this.

Comment: @RobertLewis If `degrees` is 360, it would pass the `degrees % 90 != 0` check, and go into the switch, and what would you return?

Comment: Prior to this code, I make sure 0 <= degrees <= 359.

Comment: @RobertLewis Well, Java can't (isn't smart enough to) verify such complicated semantics  of your code. It can't take your word for it either because Java tries to be a _safe_ language. If you look at the features that came out in recent years. Rather than a `@SuppressWarnings`, I would rather like some way to specify the semantics of your code, so that the compiler can reason about it :)

Comment: @RobertLewis you can always write `default -> throw new AssertionError();` when you think that it is impossible to reach that point. That’s precisely what the compiler generates when it can prove the exhaustiveness, e.g. when switching over all `enum` constants of a type. It will not allow the absence of such default code.

Comment: I think in case *expressions* the `default` case must be a value (like the other cases) and not a statement?

Comment: @RobertLewis statements that throw an exception are allowed in switch expressions, as they still fulfill the requirement of not returning without a value (they don’t return at all). That’s nothing new, e.g. you can have value-compatible lambda expressions throwing an exception, e.g. `Optional.empty().map(x -> { throw new AssertionError("should never reach here"); });`. For switch expressions, it has been considered so common, that you even can omit the braces, like in my `default -> throw new AssertionError();` example, to make it as concise as the value returning single expression cases.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different switch constructs. The switch expression and the switch statement. The switch expression is quite new (added in JDK, um, 14? Less than 2 years ago). The switch statement form, on the other hand, is 25+ years old.

The switch statement form has had the property that many linting tools and IDEs will generate a warning if you aren't covering all the cases.

However, and this is the key, **you are using the switch expression form, and compiler-provable exhaustiveness is REQUIRED by the java specification**.

In other words, for switch statements, non-exhaustiveness is fine and not an error or even a javac-spec-enforced warning, but most linters/IDEs do warn for this, but you're using the switch expression form. The spec says that an error must be generated here. There is no `@SuppressWarnings` or any other intellij settings that you can set to make intellij ignore spec requirements.

The reason for this is simple: You are using this switch as an expression, so what should the compiler presume the switch resolves to if none of the case blocks is hit?

If you say: But that can't happen - well, the compiler does not know that and crazy things can occur. At best you would presume that the compiler will then throw something, but, well, the spec says that's not how it works.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Of course, if you are fine with the idea of throwing something in that case, you can insert precisely that, .i.e. `default -> throw something;`.

Comment: I think the `default` case has to yield a value (like the other cases), and can't be a statement like `throw..`.. That's why `Optional.ofnullable(...)` works, with `default -> null`

Comment: @RobertLewis incorrect. `default -> throw...` is legal in switch expressions. Try it.